# Network-related icons suddenly removed

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, desktop, icons

On a fresh Windows 7 installation, I created some shortcuts icons to network shares on the Desktop.

Without any warning, these icons are ***sometimes*** and ***randomly*** deleted from Desktop. I totally don't understand what it happens! They are not hidden, they just are simply deleted.

This behavior occurs on one computer in my company. Others Windows 7 computers are not affected by that. And also it's the first time I encounter that.

Do you have an idea about this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a possible source of the problem is: http://www.zhacks.com/2010/03/31/windows-7-shortcuts-missing-or-disappeared-after-system-maintenance/

pulled from the google cache as the domain appears to have disappeared

"
In Windows XP, there is a Desktop Cleanup Wizard that by default runs every 60 days to move unused desktop items to a folder named “Unused Desktop Shortcuts. This feature can be disabled by right clicking the Desktop, go to Properties > Desktop tab > Customize Desktop button > uncheck Run Desktop Cleanup Wizard every 60 days. However for Windows 7, this feature has been changed to system maintenance where it cleans up unused files and shortcuts, and perform other maintenance tasks.

System maintenance is scheduled to run once a week and if it finds more than 4 bad or broken shortcuts, it will remove all of them. As for desktop shortcuts that are valid but not used for more than 3 months, they will also be removed.

To prevent this from happening, you can turn off computer maintenance from Control Panel > Troubleshooting > Change Settings > select Off for Computer Maintenance but this would mean you would stop Windows 7 from checking volume errors, and also checking for troubleshooting history and error reports that are taking up disk space. Another method is to disable checking of unused desktop icons and broken shortcuts.

```
1. Install Take Ownership right click extension if you haven’t.
2. Open My Computer and navigate to this path C:\Windows\diagnostics\scheduled\Maintenance
3. You can either delete or move this 2 files to another location on your hard drive.
TS_UnusedDesktopIcons.ps1 > For checking unused desktop icons
TS_BrokenShortcuts.ps1 < For checking broken shortcuts
```

Once both of this ps1 files are moved out of the Maintenance folder, the weekly scheduled computer maintenance will no longer check for unused or broken shortcuts and automatically remove them from your desktop.

You May Also Like:

1. Over 50 Windows 7 GodMode Shortcuts Anywhere
2. Show and Hide Desktop Icons in Windows 7
3. Windows 7 Extended Disk Cleanup With 10 Extra Items
4. Enable or Disable and Adjust Aero Peek Response in Windows 7
5. Delete Unused or Orphan DLL Library Files in Windows

Tags: broken shortcut, computer maintenance, shortcut, unused shortcut

Comments
2 Responses to “Windows 7 Shortcuts Missing or Disappeared after System Maintenance”

1.
      PD says:
      October 6, 2010 at 5:05 pm

```
  Works great!! I created a folder within the maintenance folder to store the ps1 files in case I ever need to put them back.
```

2.
      Meitzi says:
      October 21, 2010 at 1:58 pm

```
  If Not Exist “%SystemRoot%\diagnostics\scheduled\Maintenance\TS_UnusedDesktopIcons.ps1″ goto VALMIS
  takeown /a /f “%SystemRoot%\diagnostics\scheduled\Maintenance\TS_UnusedDesktopIcons.ps1″
  takeown /a /f “%SystemRoot%\diagnostics\scheduled\Maintenance\TS_BrokenShortcuts.ps1″
  icacls “%SystemRoot%\diagnostics\scheduled\Maintenance\TS_UnusedDesktopIcons.ps1″ /c /grant *S-1-5-32-544:f
  icacls “%SystemRoot%\diagnostics\scheduled\Maintenance\TS_BrokenShortcuts.ps1″ /c /grant *S-1-5-32-544:f
  md c:\drivers\backup
  del “c:\drivers\backup\TS_UnusedDesktopIcons.bak” /F
  del “c:\drivers\backup\TS_BrokenShortcuts.bak” /F
  move “%SystemRoot%\diagnostics\scheduled\Maintenance\TS_UnusedDesktopIcons.ps1″ c:\drivers\backup\
  move “%SystemRoot%\diagnostics\scheduled\Maintenance\TS_BrokenShortcuts.ps1″ c:\drivers\backup\
  :VALMIS
```

"

A scheduled clean up task that removes unused icons could be moving them

Comment: I changed the name of some of the listed .ps1 files I found thanks to your link. Maybe this will work. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: NOTE: THE ABOVE LINK IS DOWN AS OF 01-29-2011.  Please post answers in full, or quote and give reference.

Comment: @Mike there u go

Comment: The first remedy (disable maintenance) worked just fine for me; I would like to try the second one (remove TS_BrokenShortcuts.ps1) as it looks better to disable just that one thing. Nevertheless I get a message saying I can not delete/remove/rename the file for lack of privileges. It is at a computer at work(s' network), but as far as I can see I have administrative powers at it (my PC not the net). Any idea? Is there some "mega-admin" powers I don't have?

Answer (score 0):

I am an IT Admin where I work.  This was a problem for one of our users.

Windows 7 has a System Maintenance troubleshooter.  It will detect and delete broken shortcuts.  If you have a shortcut to a network drive, and the connection is intermittent (cable issue maybe), the System Maintenance troubleshooter will see the shortcut as broken.  It will be automatically deleted.

To disable the System Maintenance troubleshooter, follow the steps below.

Also, you will want to correct the intermittent connection.  First, try swapping the cable for one known to be good.

Retrieved 01-29-2011
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978980
<sub>but abridged/edited</sub>

> ### Desktop shortcuts disappear in Windows 7
>
> **SYMPTOMS** On a computer that is running
> Windows 7, shortcuts that you create
> on the desktop disappear.
>
> **CAUSE** These shortcuts are regarded as
> broken and are deleted by the System
> Maintenance troubleshooter.
>
> The System Maintenance troubleshooter
> performs a weekly maintenance of the
> operating system. The System
> Maintenance troubleshooter either
> fixes problems automatically or
> reports problems through Action
> Center. When there are more than four
> broken shortcuts on the desktop, the
> System Maintenance troubleshooter
> automatically removes all broken
> shortcuts from the desktop.
>
> **WORKAROUND** To work around this issue,
> use one of the following methods.
>
> **Method 1:** Keep the number of broken
> shortcuts on your desktop to four or
> less.
>
> **Method 2:** If you must have more than
> four broken shortcuts on your desktop,
> you can disable the System Maintenance
> troubleshooter.
>
> **Note** If you disable the System
> Maintenance troubleshooter, all the
> maintenance tasks that it performs are
> disabled. Therefore, we recommend that
> you use Method 1.
>
> To disable the System Maintenance
> troubleshooter, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Click **Start**, and then click **Control Panel**.
> 2. Under **System and Security**, click **Find and fix problems**.
> 3. On the left navigation pane, click **Change settings**.
> 4. Set **Computer Maintenance** to **Off**.
>
> **MORE INFORMATION** You may create
> shortcuts on the desktop that
> frequently become "broken." For
> example, a desktop shortcut for a USB
> device may be regarded as broken if
> the USB device is not connected when
> the System Maintenance troubleshooter
> performs its maintenance.
>
> **APPLIES TO**
>
> - Windows 7 Enterprise
> - Windows 7 Home Basic
> - Windows 7 Home Premium
> - Windows 7 Professional
> - Windows 7 Ultimate